# cp file device:directory on Minix

Tags: directory, filenames, cp, minix

In my operating systems class we had to modify the boot screen of the Minix OS. I understood just about everything we did, but at the end of the make for compiling the new OS, there's a line:

```
cp image /dev/c0d0p0:/minix/2.0.4r2
```

I don't understand what the colon is for, can anybody explain this? I've searched all over with no luck.

Comment: Were you doing the compilation under Minix, or under some other operating system?

Comment: It was in Minix.

Comment: Do you have a link to the rest of your instructions? Is this command entered in the normal shell, or in a special screen like a boot prompt? - EDIT: Are you sure it was a `cp`, and not an `mtools` copy?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. This is not a command. It is output.

The [mkboot](http://www.cis.temple.edu/~giorgio/old/cis307s05/software/minix2.0/src/tools/mkboot) script echoes this to the screen in the following section:

```bsh
echo "cp image $root:/minix/$target"
cp -p image $rootdir/minix/$target || exit
```

The `$rootdir` variable indicates a directory on which it has mounted the $root device earlier in the script, if the target root is something other than the actual mounted root:

```bsh
case $action in
bootable | hdboot)
    # We need the root device.
    if [ $realroot = $root ]
    then
        rootdir=
    else
        umount $root 2>/dev/null
        mount $root /root || exit
        rootdir=/root
    fi
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get a better answer, I'll take a near-wild guess at it:

It seems like that line allows you to copy a file to a device that may not be mounted by specifying the device `/dev/c0d0p0`  and the file `/minix/2.0.4r2`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I was actually just considering that. I think that, because it has to move the image to the boot sector (is that even right?) it would have to specify a device outside the Minix filesystem and on to the root drive. Would that make sense?

Comment: The boot sector a whole different beast.  I'll be honest, I've not used Minix in over 25 years and it was a way different beast back then... but it isn't unheard of for *nix variants to keep the boot code on a different partition.